# Dominated Irreducible Component

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

my question refers to the expression above the red tagged line in the picture:

[image]

What does it mean concretely in topological (or/and algebraic geometrical) sense if we say "an irreducible component of U DOMINATES an irreducible component of V"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A component $C\subseteq X$ dominates a component $D\subseteq Y$ under a morphism $f:X\to Y$ if $f(C)$ is a dense subset of $D$ (that is, if $f$ restricts to a dominant morphism $C\to D$).  Equivalently, $f$ maps the generic point of $C$ to the generic point of $D$.